# How to plot latex labels in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, latex

In python you can use latex labels in plots for example

```
plt.plot(x, y, label = r"xy \textbf{plot}")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

where  `r""` is used to indicate the latex part. However suppose you don't have this label in advance and receive it as a variable. How can you use it?

```
  plt.plot(x, y, label = r""+label_param)
```

does not work.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the r is there is because r"" indicates a raw string in Python, which is just telling the interpreter not to parse the backslashes as unicode (e.g. \n as a newline). So you can just take the label_param (assuming it's a unicode string) and replace all the backslashes with double backslashes:

```
label_param = label_param.replace(r"\", r"\\")
```

Your current code doesn't actually change label_param: it just adds the empty string r"" (which is the same as u"" or just "") to the beginning of label_param.

Comment: I see the point now, but this still doesn't work. python is not able to parse the line of code: label_param = label_param.replace(r"\", r"\\")

Comment: However this works: label_param = label_param.replace("\\", "\\\\"). Thanks!

Comment: it turns out that I can't print space. The space between characters are removed when using this. Even using "\ " does not solve the problem.

Comment: What do you mean spaces? LaTeX math mode removes spaces by default: if you want to have spaces, you have to put them inside a wrapper like \textbf{ }.

Comment: For more information on math mode, see [this guide](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics).

Comment: I tried that (\textit{firstword secondword}), but it doesn't seem to work... thanks for the link.